# Overriding HTTP errors with urllib2

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have this code, but it is not working. I want to use urllib2 to iterate through a list of urls. Upon opening each url, BeautifulSoup locates a class and extracts that text. The program stalls if there is an invalid url in the list. If there is any error, I just want to have 'error' as the text, and for the program to continue on to the next url. Any ideas?

```
    for url in url_list:
         page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
         soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

         text = soup.find_all(class_='ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir')
         if text is not None:
            for t in text:
                text2 = t.get_text().encode('utf-8')
         else:
            text2 = 'error'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try/except` is your friend!  Change your code to s/thing like...:

```
for url in url_list:
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        text2 = 'error'
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
        text = soup.find_all(class_='ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir')
        if text:
           for t in text:
               text2 = t.get_text().encode('utf-8')
        else:
           text2 = 'error'
```

Comment: `[] is not None` will always be True

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, and since that's what `find_all` returns on no hits I'm gonna edit my A to fix this further problem by the OP (I had originally just c&p's from the Q:-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli thank you so much! this solves it. Am I understanding correctly that it first checks for `URLError` and finally for any other error?

Comment: @textnet, no: it checks *only* for URLError, the `else:` part is executed only if there are no errors -- any other exception is unexpected here and therefore, as is best practice, it's allowed to propagate up the call stack.

Answer (score 3):

urllib2.urlopen raises URLError on error as you can find in [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)

Use try-except block:

```
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print e
```